# Swift - Expression resolves to an unused l-value

Tags: arrays, swift

Arrays stockPriceDate1..4 are used identically throughout the code. Get l-value error on last two entries. It is my list punctuation that I have got wrong?

```
func sChart(chart: ShinobiChart!, dataPointAtIndex dataIndex: Int, forSeriesAtIndex seriesIndex: Int) -> SChartData! {
    return seriesIndex == 0 ?
        stockPriceData1[dataIndex]: 
        stockPriceData2[dataIndex]; 
        stockPriceData3[dataIndex];    <- Expression resolves error...
        stockPriceData4[dataIndex]     <- Expression resolves error...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code differently:

```
return seriesIndex == 0 ? stockPriceData1[dataIndex] : stockPriceData2[dataIndex]

let _ = stockPriceData3[dataIndex]
let _ = stockPriceData4[dataIndex]
```

Note that the return value is either `stockPriceData1` or `stockPriceData2`. The next two subscripts into `stockPriceData3` and `stockPriceData4` are ignored because you are not using their results.

The code definitely doesn't do what you think it does.

If you want to use `seriesIndex` to get the correct data array, you want to use a `switch`, e.g.

```
switch seriesIndex {
   case 0:
      return stockPriceData1[dataIndex]
   case 1:
      return stockPriceData2[dataIndex]
   case 2:
      return stockPriceData3[dataIndex]
   case 3:
      return stockPriceData4[dataIndex]
   default:
      return nil // should never happen
}
```

or use an array:

```
let data = [stockPriceData1, stockPriceData2, stockPriceData3, stockPriceData4]
return data[seriesIndex][dataIndex]
```